# Calculating bowling scores with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building this bowling random score generator and I'm trying to calculate the scores on the last row of the table.

each frame score should be updated as its correspondent scores are generated. 
the scores will accumulate with the previous frame score. In addition whenever we have a strike(marked as an 'X'), the next two plays should get in that score, if we get a spare (marked as a '/'), the next play will be added. the next frame should only show its score once the previous frame is fully calculated. in example: first play we get a strike, 10 points added to frame 1, second play we get a 4, now frame 1 should show 14, third play we get a 3, frame 1 is closed with 17 and we can now show frame 2 score which will be the sum of the first frame plus the 7 points we scored, 34.

How can I make this happen? I've managed to make the code for the first two frames, but im repeating myself to much and also the second frame score is being shown as soon as we make the first click.

In addition how can avoid the NaN? I'm aware this is now happening because i do not have a conditional for when only one play is made.

many thanks in advance

```js
var controlVariable = 1;

function r(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;
var play3;
var frame = 1;
var newId1 = "s1f1";
var newId2 = "s2f1";
var scoreCount = "fs1";
var s1f1 = document.getElementById("s1f1");
var s2f1 = document.getElementById("s2f1");
var s1f2 = document.getElementById("s1f2");
var s2f2 = document.getElementById("s2f2");
var s1f3 = document.getElementById("s1f3");
var s2f3 = document.getElementById("s2f3");
var s1f4 = document.getElementById("s1f4");
var s2f4 = document.getElementById("s2f4");
var s1f5 = document.getElementById("s1f5");
var s2f5 = document.getElementById("s2f5");
var s1f6 = document.getElementById("s1f6");
var s2f6 = document.getElementById("s2f6");
var s1f7 = document.getElementById("s1f7");
var s2f7 = document.getElementById("s2f7");
var s1f8 = document.getElementById("s1f8");
var s2f8 = document.getElementById("s2f8");
var s1f9 = document.getElementById("s1f9");
var s2f9 = document.getElementById("s2f9");
var s1f10 = document.getElementById("s1f10");
var s2f10 = document.getElementById("s2f10");
var s3f10 = document.getElementById("s3f10");
var fs1 = document.getElementById("frame-score1");
var fs2 = document.getElementById("frame-score2");
var fs3 = document.getElementById("frame-score3");
var fs4 = document.getElementById("frame-score4");
var fs5 = document.getElementById("frame-score5");
var fs6 = document.getElementById("frame-score6");
var fs7 = document.getElementById("frame-score7");
var fs8 = document.getElementById("frame-score8");
var fs9 = document.getElementById("frame-score9");
var fs10 = document.getElementById("frame-score10");

function myFunction() {
  if (frame < 10) {
    if (controlVariable == 1) {
      play1 = r(min, max);
      if (play1 === 10) {
        // add value to first spot
        newId1 = "s1f" + frame;
        document.getElementById(newId1).innerHTML = "X";
        frame++;
      } else {
        //add value to first spot
        newId1 = "s1f" + frame;
        document.getElementById(newId1).innerHTML = play1;
        controlVariable++;
      }
    } else if (controlVariable == 2) {
      play2 = r(min, max - (play1 - min));
      controlVariable = 1;
      // add value to second spot
      newId2 = "s2f" + frame;
      if (play1 + play2 === 10) {
        document.getElementById(newId2).innerHTML = "/";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(newId2).innerHTML = play2;
      }
      frame++;
    }
  } else {
    if (controlVariable == 1) {
      play1 = r(min, max);
      if (play1 === 10) {
        // add value to first spot
        s1f10.innerHTML = "X";
        controlVariable++;
      } else {
        //add value to first spot
        s1f10.innerHTML = play1;
        controlVariable++;
      }
    } else if (controlVariable == 2) {
      if (play1 === 10) {
        play2 = r(min, max);
        if (play2 === 10) {
          s2f10.innerHTML = "X";
        } else if (play2 + play1 === 10) {
          s2f10.innerHTML = "/";
        } else {
          s2f10.innerHTML = play2;
        }
        controlVariable++;
      } else {
        play2 = r(min, max - (play1 - min));

        if (play2 + play1 === 10) {
          s2f10.innerHTML = "/";
          controlVariable++;
        } else if (play2 + play1 < 10) {
          s2f10.innerHTML = play2;
          document.getElementById("btn-score").style.visibility = "hidden";
          document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
        }
      }
    } else if (controlVariable == 3) {
      if ((play1 === 10 && play2 === 10) || play1 + play2 === 10) {
        play3 = r(min, max);
        if (play3 === 10) {
          s3f10.innerHTML = "X";
        } else {
          s3f10.innerHTML = play3;
        }

        document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
        document.getElementById("btn-score").style.visibility = "hidden";
      } else if (play1 === 10 && play2 < 10) {
        play3 = r(min, max - (play2 - min));
        if (play3 + play2 === 10) {
          s3f10.innerHTML = "/";
          document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
          document.getElementById("btn-score").style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
          s3f10.innerHTML = play3;
          document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "GAME OVER";
          document.getElementById("btn-score").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = [play1, play2];
  ///////
  //// calculos
  ///
  if (s1f1.innerHTML === "X") {
    if (s1f2.innerHTML === "X") {
      if (s1f3.innerHTML === "X") {
        fs1 = 30;
      } else {
        fs1 = 20 + parseInt(s1f3.innerHTML);
      }
    } else if (parseInt(s1f2.innerHTML) < 10 && s2f2.innerHTML == "/") {
      fs1 = 20;
    } else {
      fs1 = 10 + parseInt(s1f2.innerHTML) + parseInt(s2f2.innerHTML);
    }
  } else if (parseInt(s1f1.innerHTML) < 10 && s2f1.innerHTML == "/") {
    if (s1f2.innerHTML === "X") {
      fs1 = 20;
    } else {
      fs1 = 10 + parseInt(s1f2.innerHTML);
    }
  } else {
    fs1 = parseInt(s1f1.innerHTML) + parseInt(s2f1.innerHTML);
  }

  var out1 = document.getElementById("frame-score1");
  out1.innerHTML = fs1;

  if (s1f2.innerHTML === "X") {
    if (s1f3.innerHTML === "X") {
      if (s1f4.innerHTML === "X") {
        fs2 = 30;
      } else {
        fs2 = fs1 + 20 + parseInt(s1f4.innerHTML);
      }
    } else if (parseInt(s1f3.innerHTML) < 10 && s2f3.innerHTML == "/") {
      fs2 = fs1 + 20;
    } else {
      fs2 = fs1 + 10 + parseInt(s1f3.innerHTML) + parseInt(s2f3.innerHTML);
    }
  } else if (parseInt(s1f2.innerHTML) < 10 && s2f2.innerHTML == "/") {
    if (s1f2.innerHTML === "X") {
      fs1 = fs1 + 20;
    } else {
      fs2 = fs1 + 10 + parseInt(s1f2.innerHTML);
    }
  } else {
    fs2 = fs1 + parseInt(s1f2.innerHTML) + parseInt(s2f2.innerHTML);
  }

  var out2 = document.getElementById("frame-score2");
  out2.innerHTML = fs2;
}

function restart() {
  document.getElementById("btn-score").style.visibility = "visible";
  frame = 1;
  controlVariable = 1;
  s1f1.innerHTML = "";
  s2f1.innerHTML = "";
  s1f2.innerHTML = "";
  s2f2.innerHTML = "";
  s1f3.innerHTML = "";
  s2f3.innerHTML = "";
  s1f4.innerHTML = "";
  s2f4.innerHTML = "";
  s1f5.innerHTML = "";
  s2f5.innerHTML = "";
  s1f6.innerHTML = "";
  s2f6.innerHTML = "";
  s1f7.innerHTML = "";
  s2f7.innerHTML = "";
  s1f8.innerHTML = "";
  s2f8.innerHTML = "";
  s1f9.innerHTML = "";
  s2f9.innerHTML = "";
  s1f10.innerHTML = "";
  s2f10.innerHTML = "";
  s3f10.innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("gameOver").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 1</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 2</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 3</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 4</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 5</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 6</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 7</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 8</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 9</td>
    <td colspan="6">Frame 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f1"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f1"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f2"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f2"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f3"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f3"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f4"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f4"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f5"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f5"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f6"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f6"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f7"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f7"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f8"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f8"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s1f9"></td>
    <td colspan="3" id="s2f9"></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="s1f10"></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="s2f10"></td>
    <td colspan="2" id="s3f10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score1"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score2"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score3"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score4"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score5"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score6"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score7"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score8"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score9"></td>
    <td colspan="6" id="frame-score10"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="myFunction()" id="btn-score">Click me</button>
<button onclick="restart()" id="btn-restart">Restart</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="gameOver"></p>
```

Comment: you should *really* consider using loops more...

Comment: try not to nest if-else's unless you *have* to. 9/10 you can write a if-elseif...-else block instead.

Comment: good sugestion, in this case how would address this code? where would you add a loop?